# Client side onTextChanged

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, web-applications

I have two textbox, one with a start date an one with a end date. I like to have the end date changed to the start date, if the end date textbox is empty and the start date textbox is set to a date with out a postback.
Therefore I write this js-method:

```
function AutoFillOut() {
    if ($(".txtDateToEvent").val() == "")
        $(".txtDateToEvent").Val() = $(".txtDateFromEvent").Val();
    return false;
}
```

And inserted this statement in the page_load method:

```
 txtDateFromEvent.Attributes.Add("onTextChanged", "javascript:AutoFillOut(this);");
```

I also tried onKeyUp and OnChange instead of OnTextChanged.

Changed AutoFillOut to

```
function AutoFillOut() {
    if ($("#<%=txtDateToEvent.ClientID%>").val() == "")
        $("#<%=txtDateToEvent.ClientID%>").Val($("#<%=txtDateFromEvent.ClientID%>").Val())  ;
    return false;
}
```

But still doesn't work.

Solution: 
JS:

```
function AutoFillOut() {
    if ($('#<%=txtDateToEvent.ClientID%>').val() == "")
        $('#<%=txtDateToEvent.ClientID%>').val($('#<%=txtDateFromEvent.ClientID%>').val())  ;
    return false;
}
```

Page_Load

```
txtDateFromEvent.Attributes.Add("onChange", "javascript:AutoFillOut()");
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: if you could made [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with the snippet tool I can help to fix your code, there are a few mistakes. For example, to set the value of `txtDateToEvent` input you should use `$(".textDateToEvent").val($(".txtDateFromEvent").Val());`

Comment: I changed the code like you mentioned, butt it doesn't help

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example

Comment: Please, at least add the `html` markup of the textboxes. Maybe you are capturing the wrong event, will be hard to tell without knowing the context of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add an attribute to the TextBox in code behind. You can add a listener with jQUery.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDateFromEvent" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDateToEvent" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#<%= txtDateToEvent.ClientID %>').blur(function () {
            if ($('#<%= txtDateToEvent.ClientID %>').val() === '') {
                $('#<%= txtDateToEvent.ClientID %>').val($('#<%= txtDateFromEvent.ClientID %>').val());
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this also

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDateFromEvent" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDateToEvent" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('body').on('blur','input[id*=txtDateToEvent]', '', function () {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                $(this).val($('input[id*=txtDateFromEvent]').val());
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```